# Creating similarity measures between pairs in data organized by dyad-years

Tags: igraph

I have data organized in this way:

```
country1 country2 year ally

USA      USSR     1990  0

USA      UK       1990  1

UK       USSR     1990  0

USA      USSR     1992  0

USA      UK       1992  1

UK       USSR     1992  1
```

What I want to do is to have another vector that contains the similarity scores for each pair of countries per year. Is there any easy way to do this in `iGraph`? Thanks.

Comment: Is it igraph in R, Python, C or Mathematica?

Comment: How do you define the similarity between two countries?